# How divide or multiply every non-string columns of a PySpark dataframe with a float constant?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input dataframe looks like the below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=[('Alice',4.300,None),('Bob',float('nan'),897)],schema=['name','High','Low'])

+-----+----+----+
| name|High| Low|
+-----+----+----+
|Alice| 4.3|null|
|  Bob| NaN| 897|
+-----+----+----+
```

Expected Output if divided by 10.0

```
+-----+----+----+
| name|High| Low|
+-----+----+----+
|Alice| 0.43|null|
|  Bob| NaN| 89.7|
+-----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know about any library function that could do this, but this snippet seems to do job just fine:

```
CONSTANT = 10.0

for field in df.schema.fields:
    if str(field.dataType) in ['DoubleType', 'FloatType', 'LongType', 'IntegerType', 'DecimalType']:
        name = str(field.name)
        df = df.withColumn(name, col(name)/CONSTANT)


df.show()
```

outputs:

```
+-----+----+----+
| name|High| Low|
+-----+----+----+
|Alice|0.43|null|
|  Bob| NaN|89.7|
+-----+----+----+
```

Comment: you're missing DecimalType.

Comment: this code throws `NameError: name 'col' is not defined`

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav  `col` is a pyspark function. You have to import it with `from pyspark.sql.functions import col`. Or you can just do `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` and get all the helper functions, but some people don't believe in that.

Comment: Hi, what if you want the function to return an integer type? I tried `df = df.withColumn(name, round(col(name)/CONSTANT))` but it returns a single decimal number

Comment: Sorry I found the solution: after the division you just run this: `df = df.withColumn(name, col(name).cast(IntegerType()))`

Comment: This code is not efficient if you have a long list of columns.

Answer (score 10):

The below code should solve your problem in a time efficient manner

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

allowed_types = ['DoubleType', 'FloatType', 'LongType', 'IntegerType', 'DecimalType']

df = df.select(*[(col(field.name)/10).name(field.name) if str(field.dataType) in allowed_types else col(field.name) for field in df.schema.fields]
```

Using "withColumn" iteratively might not be a good idea when the number of columns is large.
This is because PySpark dataframes are immutable, so essentially we will be creating a new DataFrame for each column casted using withColumn, which will be a very slow process.

This is where the above code comes in handy.