# Multiplication of all PySpark dataframe columns by float value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's imagine I have the following PySpark dataframe:

```
data = [(20,40,60),
    (50,40,30),
    (20,50,30),
    (40,60,70),
    (50,50,60)
  ]

columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
```

I also have a parameter, called "ponderation", of the type 'float';
I want to multiply all the columns in `df` by `ponderation` and have tried the following:

```
ponderation_int = int(ponderation)
df2 = df.columns*ponderation_int
```

This would, even if it worked, not be ideal because I want the float and not the int type.

I have tried simply

```
df2 = df.columns*ponderation
```

And also the option listed in both answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807818/how-divide-or-multiply-every-non-string-columns-of-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-a-fl) question. None of the options have worked.
Does anyone know how I can implement this? Or do I need to multiply each column individually?

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried with the linked answer? I don't see why the linked answer would not work.

Comment: You can't multiple `df.columns` because it is a list of column names in Python and is irrelevant to the dataframe itself

Comment: @mck `df2 = df.select(*[(col(field.name)*ponderation).name(field.name) if str(field.dataType) in allowed_types else col(field.name) for field in df.schema.fields]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted the answer you linked and it worked for me:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [(20,40,60),
    (50,40,30),
    (20,50,30),
    (40,60,70),
    (50,50,60)
  ]
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)

ponderation = 0.5

for field in df.schema.fields:
    if str(field.dataType) in ['DoubleType', 'FloatType', 'LongType', 'IntegerType', 'DecimalType']:
        name = str(field.name)
        df = df.withColumn(name, F.col(name) * ponderation)

df.show()
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   C|
+----+----+----+
|10.0|20.0|30.0|
|25.0|20.0|15.0|
|10.0|25.0|15.0|
|20.0|30.0|35.0|
|25.0|25.0|30.0|
+----+----+----+
```

In fact the other answer also worked:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
df2 = df.select(*[(F.col(field.name)*ponderation).name(field.name) if str(field.dataType) in allowed_types else F.col(field.name) for field in df.schema.fields])

df2.show()
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   C|
+----+----+----+
|10.0|20.0|30.0|
|25.0|20.0|15.0|
|10.0|25.0|15.0|
|20.0|30.0|35.0|
|25.0|25.0|30.0|
+----+----+----+
```

I suspect you didn't import `pyspark.sql.functions` and so `col` was not defined.

Comment: I had already imported it. Your code works, as in no errors are encoutered, but however, my "ponderation" value is 0.216 and the output I obtain for each column is the original value from df?

Comment: @Johanna maybe the result was not assigned to a new variable? I edited the second code snippet to do that. In the first code snippet the dataframe was modified in place, so it *should* make some changes to your dataframe, unless all columns were strings...

Comment: Using the second answer provided I already obtained the expected output!

Comment: Even without assigning it to a new variable. The first answer, indeed, is not working for me

Comment: Hmm, strange. I like the second answer though - I never liked reassigning dataframe variables in Spark, as in the first answer.